# Ldap query for Authentication based on AD security group

Tags: filter, ldap, bind, redcap

I've seen a couple of posts here on this topic, but I can't manage to authenticate by users in a group. If I point the path to where a user is, authentication is successful.  It's like it "cannot read" inside the group. I'm must be missing something.

my configs are:

```
$GLOBALS['ldapdsn'] = array(
   // primary  server MS AD Server
   // port 636 is ldaps and port 389 is ldap
        array(
        'url'    => '172.25.20.3',
        'port'   => '389',
        'version'    => '3',
        'referral'   => 'false',
        'basedn' => 'CN=RedcapUsers,OU=RedCap,OU=Srv,DC=mydomain,DC=com',
        'binddn' => 'CN=RedcapLdap,OU=RedCap,OU=Srv,DC=mydomain,DC=com',
        'bindpw'     => 'mypass',
        'attributes' => array('sAMAccountName'),
        'userattr'   => 'sAMAccountName',
        'userfilter' => '(objectClass=user)',
        ), //
```

- RedcapUsers is the AD group.
- Binding works fine.

I'm pretty new in code writing.

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to do or what language you are using? Read:https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Filter the AD group ( See last line of code) and issue is resolved !

```
'url'        => 'Active Directory ip',
'port'       => '636',
'version'    => '3',
'referral'   => 'false',
'basedn'     => 'OU=Users,DC=Ali,DC=local',  // Must be exact OU where users are 
'binddn'     => 'CN=service_redcap,OU=Users,DC=Ali,DC=local', //-- User who give access to AD
'bindpw'     => 'myPassword', // ---Password to above user
'attributes' => array('samAccountName'),
'userattr'   => 'samAccountName',
'userfilter' => '(memberOf=CN=REDCAP_GROUP,DC=Ali,DC=local)'  //-- Users in this group will loging to Redcap
```